# How to restore deleted post related with deleted users

Tags: posts, customization

I accidentally deleted post that related to certain users in wordpress because I deleted user.
How can I restore those posts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Pages/Post-->All Pages/Posts-->Click Trash, then restore them....